# btrfs Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: btrfs

so many error and after days i can't find how to fix

```
parent transid verify failed on 319143936 wanted 6735 found 6601
parent transid verify failed on 319143936 wanted 6735 found 6601
parent transid verify failed on 319700992 wanted 6735 found 6604
parent transid verify failed on 319700992 wanted 6735 found 6604
parent transid verify failed on 319717376 wanted 6735 found 6603
parent transid verify failed on 319717376 wanted 6735 found 6603
parent transid verify failed on 338149376 wanted 6735 found 6622
parent transid verify failed on 338149376 wanted 6735 found 6622
parent transid verify failed on 426164224 wanted 6735 found 6718
parent transid verify failed on 426164224 wanted 6735 found 6718
parent transid verify failed on 426164224 wanted 6735 found 6718
parent transid verify failed on 426164224 wanted 6735 found 6718
Ignoring transid failure
parent transid verify failed on 426164224 wanted 6735 found 6718
Ignoring transid failure
parent transid verify failed on 426164224 wanted 6735 found 6718
Ignoring transid failure
parent transid verify failed on 426164224 wanted 6735 found 6718
Ignoring transid failure
parent transid verify failed on 425803776 wanted 6735 found 6639
parent transid verify failed on 425803776 wanted 6735 found 6639
parent transid verify failed on 425803776 wanted 6735 found 6639
parent transid verify failed on 425803776 wanted 6735 found 6639
Ignoring transid failure
leaf parent key incorrect 425803776
bad block 425803776
ERROR: errors found in extent allocation tree or chunk allocation
parent transid verify failed on 426164224 wanted 6735 found 6718
Ignoring transid failure
parent transid verify failed on 427311104 wanted 6735 found 6718
parent transid verify failed on 427311104 wanted 6735 found 6718
parent transid verify failed on 427311104 wanted 6735 found 6718
parent transid verify failed on 427311104 wanted 6735 found 6718
Ignoring transid failure
parent transid verify failed on 427261952 wanted 6735 found 6639
parent transid verify failed on 427261952 wanted 6735 found 6639
parent transid verify failed on 427261952 wanted 6735 found 6639
parent transid verify failed on 427261952 wanted 6735 found 6639
Ignoring transid failure
parent transid verify failed on 427360256 wanted 6735 found 6718
parent transid verify failed on 427360256 wanted 6735 found 6718
parent transid verify failed on 427360256 wanted 6735 found 6718
parent transid verify failed on 427360256 wanted 6735 found 6718
Ignoring transid failure
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: same problem here - with 4.15.0-15-generic and btrfs progs v4.4